# mysql 1142 error code

Tags: php, mysql

I have been reading a tutorial. I copy and pasted this code below into mysql database:

```
CREATE TABLE `databasename`.`users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `username` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
  `password` VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

However, i get this error:

> 1142 - CREATE command denied to user 'me'@'localhost' for table 'users'

In mysql database i have given all the privileges. 
I know nothing about PHP code. So i am unable to figure what the problem is. Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: "*i have given all the privileges*" - how did you do this?  how have you verified it?

Comment: @eggyal he can do that simply form phpmyadimn

Comment: @Eritrea: Who said the OP was using phpMyAdmin?

Comment: "I know nothing about PHP code" - there's no PHP here, is there? You're not running that statement from PHP are you?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `databasename`  database running with that name on your installation. Create the DB or verify that you have no typo.

BTW you should not store the password in plain text. That is what it looks like. Generate a salted hash and store that.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you do not assign the user me@localhost the privilege  creative control. To resolve this issue, go to phpmyadmin, click the ongler privileges and create privileges in the user box me@localhost ..